# Visual Studio Online build fails randomly when compiling Azure projects

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-devops

I have a couple of build definitions for continuous integration running on VSO using an on-premises server. The thing is that sometimes they fail because Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets was not able to copy some files when building the Azure projects (while building locally, both using VS or MSBuild, works always).
The basic structure of my solution is as follows:

```
Solution
|_Azure.Web.App
| |_Roles
|   |_Web.App
|_Web.App
  |_Controllers
  |_Models
  |_Resources
  | |_File1.csv
  | |_File2.csv
  |_Startup
  | |_File3.cmd
  | |_File4.xml
  | |_File5.msi
  |_Views
```

And the problem is that files from Resources and Startup folders are not copied to the output directory when building Azure.Web.App, showing this error:

> ### [error]C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Windows Azure Tools\2.7\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets(2787,5): Error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "Resources\File1.csv" because it was not found.

All files are set to always copy to output directory and the build actions are as follows:

- Content for CSV and XML files.
- None for CMD and MSI files.

I haven't been able to pinpoint the circumstances when this happens, and they seem pretty random to me. Generally triggering again the build manually and/or deleting the source files at the agent directory before building again solve the issue, which is not ideal, as continuous integration is unreliable at the moment.
Have had a good look at all existing topics but haven't found one that fits my situation. Sorry if the question has already been asked, and thanks in advance.

EDIT: Forgot to mention I'm talking about new build definitions based on vNext (not XML-based builds).

Comment: Setting "Clean Workspace" to "All" in your build definition to see if you can still see this issue.

Comment: Thanks Eddie! Are you talking about the "Clean" option that appears at Visual Studio Build step? I'll try this and see how it goes.

Comment: Yes, also set "Clean" option under "Repository" tab to "true" in your build definition.

Comment: Hey again Eddie, thanks for your answer. I've been monitoring the builds health for the last couple of days and everything was working nicely until we had a build failing yesterday and one today. Do you happen to have some other ideas? Could it be due to the server where we are running the agent?

Comment: What is the error message when the build fails?

Comment: The error keeps being the same one:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Windows Azure Tools\2.7\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets (2787, 5)
Could not copy the file "StartUp\Something.msi" because it was not found.`
Followed by a lot of other related errors with other files.

Comment: I have a build in VSTS that hits this same MSB3030 error (on the exact same line of `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets`, although I'm using 2.8) every single time - not at all intermittent. (Local msbuild runs fine.) The obvious thing in common with your example is that I have files with a build action of Content that are in a subfolder of a project being built into a role (although in my case, they're in a separate project, which is referenced by the web project being built into the web role).

Comment: ...but I found that the all-too-common workaround of `/m:1` (described in my answer) seems to make it stop happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that in some cases where this particular error occurs, you can stop it from happening by passing a `/m:1` option in the "MSBuild arguments" setting for the MSBuild step.

This prevents concurrent builds, forcing MSBuild to process things one project at a time. Sadly, this seems to be a workaround for quite a lot of build problems.

Comment: Thanks Ian, I've just added that parameter and will monitor build's health for a couple of days. Crossing my fingers!

Comment: Hey Ian, thanks a lot! That argument did the trick. Still unsure of why those resources were not found in the first place, but CI is solid now.